# How to read text file of float numbers efficiently with Java + LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, file, input, libgdx

I'm writing a small scientific data visualization app with Java/LibGDX. The app first reads in a text file that describes a 4d array:

```
188 225 3 6 0.001 -0.023 1.345 2.475 ... 4.327
```

The first four integers specify the dimension of the array: 188 x 255 x 3 x 6, followed by 188 x 255 x 3 x 6 ~= 760000 numbers. In total, the text file takes about 5MB space.

The 4D array represents an 'augmented' image of 188 pixels tall and 255 pixels wide with 3 color channels (RGB). There are 6 'parameters' associated with each pixel channel, instead of just one as in regular RGB images.

I used the following way that I copied from the official document to read the space-separated list into memory:

```
FileHandle ptmFile = Gdx.files.internal(filename);
String ptmText= ptmFile.readString();
```

Then I created a simple wrapper class AugPixel, which is practically a wrapper of a 6-element array for each pixel. I used a Scanner to read and parse each number from the string (Please pardon me for the semi-pseudo code):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(ptmText);
int nRows = scan.nextInt();
int nCols = scan.nextInt();
int nColors = scan.nextInt();
int nParams = scan.nextInt();


AugPixel[][][] im = new AugPixel[nRows][nCols][nColors];

for (i = 1~nRows)
  for (j = 1~nCols)
    for (k = 1~nColors)
      im[i][j][k] = new AugPixel(nParams);
      for (m = 1~nParams) 
        im[i][j][k].addParam(scan.nextFloat());
```

This method works fine for the desktop version. It takes about 5 seconds to load the file and build all the AugPixel objects. However, when I move the app to an actual android device (Nexus 7 32G (2nd generation)), the loading process takes 5 minutes!

So my questions is: Is there any way to speed up the loading process? I have the freedom to redefine the organization of the file as I see fit.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it might be faster if you first read the whole file into memory (maybe with `Files.readAllBytes`) and then process it. Maybe the many small file accesses are slowing it down.

Comment: @noone Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately I think my current program is  already using this strategy. It calls FileHandle.readString() to read the entire file into a long String in one bulk, then uses Scanner to parse each number in the string. Alternately, maybe I can store the float numbers as binary data as opposed to text. I'll see how that works out. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see that now, I've missed your call of ptmFile.readString(). Probably you should profile your program to find out what the main bottleneck is. Maybe it's even the conversion of 760k Strings to floats.

Comment: Yes it turns out the string conversion is the main bottleneck. I now get rid of that part and the loading time is satisfactory. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If reading the data from the file is the main bottleneck, you could attempt to use some form of asynchronous IO so that you can process portions of the string while loading the rest.

If the main bottleneck is parsing the string, you could somehow attempt to multi-thread the process or switch to a binary file format. If you are willing to abandon a text format the best solution is probably to switch to a binary file format, this should substantially decrease processing time and possibly file size.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll look into it and see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: More than likely (You should still profile), the bottleneck is with the String to float conversion. If that's the case you can either multi-thread as I suggested, or if possible use a binary file. The binary file would substantially decrease processing time (And perhaps file size).

Comment: You are absolutely right! It turns out that the String parsing takes most of the time. I now redefine the file in binary format, and now it loads within a second on the Android device! Thank you so much for your help!